# Data Stores in EXT Js not loading consistently

Tags: extjs

So I have run into this a bunch of times and it is really stumping me and my team.  I am using files created with EXT JS Designer (3) so that means the *ListStore.js, *.ui.js, and *.js

I have tried setting callback to load and tried using *getStore().removeAll(), and *getStore().load() but nothing consistently works.

The question I have is what is the best way to ensure that the data store is loaded?

Some examples would be great.  I can post example if needed but I dont want to band-aid my code, I want to do it right.

Comment: Some examples from you would be good too... You're saying it doesn't work consistently and you don't post any code...

Comment: put up your example on jsfiddle.net so we can see what is happening. you should also learn debugging with firebug or CDT

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS 4.0 does have a callback on load.  It looks something like this:

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success)
            // fire off some events here
        else
            // do something else
    }
});
```

Now, IIRC, ExtJS 4.0 does not handle success: and failure: callbacks like ExtJS 3 did.  In fact, on a failure the callback: won't event be called, so nothing ever enters the else block above.  success: and failure: calls should be addressed in ExtJS 4.1.